# Python Nested Dictionaries Problems

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a looping room game, where you can continuously go into different rooms if the option is available.

I'm having trouble understanding the problems with the `print(list_rooms[room[direction]])` line. The error code states that string indices must be integers, but I cannot think of a different way to word what I'm trying to accomplish. I don't see how in the posted example, `Bedroom` is not printed.

Is this a formatting error? Or something more complex? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
list_rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'south': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'north': 'Great Hall', 'east': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'west': 'Bedroom'}
    }

cardinal_directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
room = 'Great Hall'

while True:
    print('You are currently in the {}.'.format(room))
    direction = input('Where do you go? Type south for south, west for west, ect. Type exit to leave\n').strip()
    if direction in cardinal_directions:
        if direction in list_rooms[room]:
            print(list_rooms[room[direction]])
            #  room = list_rooms[room[direction]]
        else:
            print('That is not a valid direction')
    elif direction == 'exit':
        print('Goodbye')
        exit()
    else:
        print('That is not a valid command')
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here, so people can easily see it?

Comment: Here's an Imgur link with line numbers https://imgur.com/FO2WYEI  The line I'm having trouble with is line 19. Line 20 was supposed to take its place once I can figure out the proper formatting. Additionally, I'll try to format my code into the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please don't provide images of code or links to code stored on another site.  Put the code itself in your SO question as formatted text. Since such text won't have line numbers, tell us clearly on which line the error occurs.

Comment: @Steve: They edited in the code the instant I closed it with the third vote; I voted to reopen, but need a couple more to do so (a real traceback would still be nice, but I think they have barely enough info that it no longer qualifies for closure).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - it sounds like the OP got the help they needed.  I don't see this therefore being worth reopening, as there's nothing novel here. With your rep, I bet you agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here `room` is a string and not the room Object. You want to use the object, so instead of doing this
`print(list_rooms[room[direction]])`

do this:

`next_room = list_rooms[room][direction]`

`print(list_rooms[next_room])`